# Convert RSS Calendar Feed to Google Calendar/iCal Format

Tags: rss, google-calendar, calendar.app

I'd like to subscribe to my univeristy's online calendar with iCal. This used to work perfectly until recently they switched to an rss calendar feed and I can't seem to find a way to add it to iCal. Google calendar won't accept it either so I have to go to the website every time I want to see the schedule, very annoying. Anyone know how I can convert the rss feed to a format iCal and/or google calendar will accept?

Comment: Does the RSS feed include ics formatted entries?  Could you post a sanitised entry from the RSS feed?  It seems likely you are going to need a script to convert it.

Comment: this is the url to the online calendar; http://www.campbell.edu/calendar/month/

and this is supposedly the rss feed of that calendar; http://www.campbell.edu/calendar/rss/